# Resource management in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

We have several Java web-applications that need to be deployed on the same machine, over tomcat. The web-applications are not related to each other. Some of them do intensive I/O and CPU operations and consume much memory.

Under the above conditions, which approach is recommended - having a single tomcat with multiple webapps, or multiple tomcats each running a single webapp ?

If all webapps are deployed on the same tomcat, is there a way to guarantee minimum resources per webapp ? I.e. minimum amount of memory, number of threads, etc.

Thanks,
Arnon.

Answer (score 0):

What we did at our company is we run 1 application per instance of Tomcat.  We originally started with multiple instances and it occurred occasionally that one application would affect the other, especially if you had to restart the Tomcat instance.

One thing that might be worth evaluating is Spring's TC Server.

http://www.springsource.com/developer/tcserver

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @tjg184 's experience. I would recommend running a tomcat per application instance. If you have a decent config and process management system, the incremental cost is not all that high and it gives you the best isolation possible without separate vm's for each tomcat instance. You could start with a single tomcat and some solid monitoring and then see if you need to move to one tomcat per app.